# Simple HTML dom removing content from displayed

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Trying to get all of the posts from my search page and display them as related search queries on the content page using [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com/search.php?q=Song Artist - Song Name');
$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'media-body';
$html->find('div[class=media-body]', 0);
echo $html;
```

Currently this works but it includes the header of the page, and the footer of the page I only want the content within the div `media-body` to be printed as **html**

(*I am also a new developer so I could be doing this completely wrong all together..*)

Comment: I am new to simple_html_dom, but does this help: `echo $html->find('body div[class=media-body]', 0);`

Comment: Are you sure there is a `<div>` on the page?

Comment: @HasseBjörk I just messed around with that for a couple of minutes and every-time it just prints a blank page. :(

Comment: You need valid HTML first.  See: https://validator.unl.edu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fimgclacks.com%2Ff%2Ftest.php.  The  `Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.
From line 1, column 1; to line 1, column 24
<div class="media-body"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to library doc (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) if you want to get the **content** of any element you need to do this (for example):

```
$ret = $html->find('div[class=media-body]');
echo $res->innertext;
```

links:

1. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#container_find
2. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

Comment: Thanks for this, this actually fixed my issue but now it's only displaying one post at a time.. so back to trouble shooting!

Comment: I'm glad to hear. Do you have multiple `.media-body` in your html?